# Using a DevX LookUpEdit control, with a GridControl, how can I hide column headings?

Tags: wpf, xaml, devexpress

I currently have the following DevExpress WPF `LookUpEdit` control in my Xaml file.  For the life of me, I can't find a way to hide the header row on the internal grid control.  I'd like a very basic, single-column Tree View control. How can this be done?

```
            <dxg:LookUpEdit x:Name="hierarchy" 
                    Grid.Column="3" 
                    Grid.Row="1" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                    Height="22"
                    Width="120" 
                    Margin="0,2,0,3" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                    FilterCondition="Contains" 
                    ImmediatePopup="True" 
                    ValueMember="nodeName" 
                    DisplayMember="description" 
                    EditValue="{Binding nodeName}"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource nodesSrc}}"
                    AutoPopulateColumns="False">
                <dxg:LookUpEdit.PopupContentTemplate>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <dxg:GridControl >
                            <dxg:GridControl.Columns>
                                <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="description" />
                            </dxg:GridControl.Columns>
                            <dxg:GridControl.View>
                                <dxg:TreeListView 
                                    AutoWidth="True"
                                    KeyFieldName="id"
                                    ParentFieldName="parentID"
                                    TreeDerivationMode="Selfreference">
                                </dxg:TreeListView>
                            </dxg:GridControl.View>
                        </dxg:GridControl>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </dxg:LookUpEdit.PopupContentTemplate>
            </dxg:LookUpEdit>
```

Comment: `<dxg:TreeListView ShowColumnHeaders="False"/>` or something like that.

Comment: Thanks HighCore.  That's the answer.  I'm new to WPF and DevX... there are just so many properties to search through...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, take a look at the [Column Header Panel](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument7569) help-article - you can control this panel's visibility via the [TreeListView.ShowColumnHeaders](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WPF/DevExpressXpfGridDataViewBase_ShowColumnHeaderstopic.aspx) property.

P.S. Further, I suggest you to use the [Visual Elements](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument6085) documentation-section that describe the control elements that you see on screen. Each sub-topic of this section contains a screenshot that outlines the described element and a brief overview of the element's purpose. Additionally, each topic contains a list of the settings that specify the element's visibility, content and appearance.